# Different tab width for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout & ViewPager.
I am trying to change the size of the Tab, like Whatsapp (camera icon).
The size of the three Tabs is equal, but the Tab of the camera is smaller.
In every attempt I make the size of the Tabs remains the same (equal across all tabs).
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: there are 4 ping icon ,3 png have same heights and widths.One is different like camera icon.

Comment: I try to change the sizes, but it's impossible.
They always come out in equal size

Answer (score 33):

You need to lower the weight of the LinearLayout of the corresponding tab.

```
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(YOUR_TAB_NUMBER));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = YOUR_WEIGHT; // e.g. 0.5f
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you! But, is there any way to set tab width as wrap_content?

Comment: I found it. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This work like champ!.. but after using this facing background color padding issue. same as @sembozdemir

Comment: Doesn't work with Viewpager2 (get Nullpointer Exception)

Answer (score 20):

@digger's answer is working. However, if you want the tab which has an icon only wraps its content, you can set weight to `0` and width to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`. It worked for me.

```
fun TabLayout.setTabWidthAsWrapContent(tabPosition: Int) {
    val layout = (this.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout).getChildAt(tabPosition) as LinearLayout
    val layoutParams = layout.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.weight = 0f
    layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    layout.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have taken 5 tabs and made 1st tab width is 12% of screen width and rest 4 are sharing remaining width. Doing it after some delay of 400 msec after inflating the views.

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

```
    int width= displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int widthOtherThanFirst= (int) ((float)width*(8.80f/10f));
    int allOther=widthOtherThanFirst/4;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LinearLayout layout1 = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout1.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams1.width = width-widthOtherThanFirst; 
            layout1.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            layout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

            LinearLayout layout2 = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout2.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams2.width = allOther; 
            layout2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

            LinearLayout layout5 = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams5 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout5.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams5.width = allOther; 
            layout5.setLayoutParams(layoutParams5);

            LinearLayout layout3 = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout3.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams3.width = allOther;
            layout3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);

            LinearLayout layout4 = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(4));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams4 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout4.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams4.width = allOther; 
            layout4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);

            tabLayout.invalidate();

        }
    },400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this for dynamic width with wrap_content background

```
private fun setTabwidth(tabposition: Int, weight: Float) {
        val layout: LinearLayout = tabLayout?.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout).getChildAt(tabpos) as LinearLayout
        val layoutParams: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = layout.getLayoutParams() as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.weight = weight 
        layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)

        val tablayoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams? = tabLayout?.layoutParams
        tablayoutParams?.width=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        tabLayout?.layoutParams=tablayoutParams
    }
```

Usage:

```
setTabwidth(0,0.4f) // first tab 0.4 weight
setTabwidth(1,0.6f) // second tab 0.6 weight
```