# Android : How to change width of individual tabs in tab layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I am trying to resize notification tab at the start of tab layout as in image,

[image]

Till now I am able to bring all three tabs as in image except the width. My progress till now is as follow,

[image]

So my question is, how do I resize individual items in a tab layout?
I searched on many pages and tried reading the documentation but didn't find anything useful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is late but better late than never. Also I can't see how **Parth Patel** answer is even related to this question.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709534/different-tab-width-for-tablayout), you will find what you are looking for.

```
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(YOUR_TAB_NUMBER));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = YOUR_WEIGHT; // e.g. 0.5f
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this TabLayout.

**layout.xml** file

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabCauses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />
```

**style.xml** file

```
  <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF26221E</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semibold_1</item>
</style>
```