# How to set 2 tab takes equal width in tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-styles

I am adding 2 tabs in the `TabLayout`, and following is my code.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_statistics"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_statistics"
    app:tabContentStart="24dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I am getting the following output.

[image]

But I want tabs to take the full width of the screen, as follows.

[image]

Following is my `AppTabLayout` style defined in `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@null</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you try with `android:layout_width="0dp"`? `match_parent` is not supported inside `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec : Tanks for the reply, I tried `0dp` but still getting the same output.

Comment: @Kirmani88 answer below is correct, need to add just one line app:tabMaxWidth="0dp", if not, you should show whole layout

Comment: have you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44983608/6176003

Comment: Use SlidingTabLayout.

Answer (score 12):

Just add the following.

```
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use style

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

reference

[Full width tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188097/6334037)

Answer (score 0):

match_parent is not supported by ConstraintLayout. Set width to 0dp to let it match constraints.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#RelativePositioning):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
>   ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
>   MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
>   constraints being set to "parent".

Answer (score 0):

You should be use stretchColumns in Table Layout

```
<TableLayout
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp">
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do as below. This is work for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use `app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"` in the `TabLayout`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I succeeded in getting the accepted output with just this one line of code: `app:tabMode="fixed".`

Full code of my TabLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="?titleTextColor"
            android:background="?android:statusBarColor" />
```

The Output of my code:

[image: The Output of my code:]

Answer (score -1):

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/overTimeCV"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

Check with this TabLayout along with viewPager