# is there any way to change each tablayout item width in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

My TabLayout is:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_nav_bar_gray"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />
```

Also, I am adding tab item like this using this java code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout =findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_black));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(selectedFolder));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Calender"));
        final MainPageTabLayoutAdapter adapter = new 
        MainPageTabLayoutAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

It is showing something like this: [image]

But I want to make it something like this with the default swipe animation[left to right] / [right to left] of tab change of a tab layout.

[image: How to make first tab item width less than the other tab item as per below image]

Comment: is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709534/different-tab-width-for-tablayout

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got exactly what I want.